# AG-Grid export using getDataAsExcel

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag grid to export the table refering to [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/export/) link.

We are able to export using `exportDataAsExcel` method and downloaded excel sheet is having sheet name as `ag grid`.

Can we configure the sheet name to something else ?

I have also tried using `getDataAsExcel` method which returns the result as a string rather than download it.

however I am not able to download to excel sheet using `getDataAsExcel`.

SO basically how can we change sheet name to something else OR is there any other way to export as excel in ag-grid so than sheet name can be configured.

To reproduce we can use same example given in the [ag-grid documentation](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the sheet name using the `exportDataAsExcel`, and passing the `sheetName` in the `params` for the function.

There's a demo of setting the sheet name in the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/excel-export/#example-excel-export-without-styles).